# What is the pixel width of the code blocks?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, images

I just want to know the width of the code block, I guess you can say of the posting area. The reason I want to know is for the purpose of centering images. When I create an image to go with an answer, I want to make it the width of the posting area so that the image appears centered. Or is there another way to center the image?

Comment: Posting an image larger than the post area will result in it being resized to fit (and thus it will appear justified, rather than centered, but in context, essentially the same thing).

Comment: Your question is 660px wide

Comment: @Flyk I was just talking about images smaller than the width. I just put the image on a white background, but I needed to know the pixel so i could center it. But if there's another way to center smaller pictures my ears are open. I'd rather do it another way than to have to do it my way :)

Comment: @peeskillet there's no way center text/images as far as I know. It was probably already asked though, will check...

Comment: Didn't find anything about centering images or text, feel free to start new support question or feature request asking for such a thing, though can't promise it will be popular request.

Comment: @peeskillet Please note that a lot of us use the mobile browser view of Stack Exchange sites regularly, and there's an Android App for Stack Exchange currently in beta, and an iOS app currently in development. In those environments, depending on the hardware in use, your attempt to center the image by padding will just make it much harder to see, since it will be shrunk down much smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it adjusts to different screen resolution? Like some kind of fluid layout?

Comment: @peeskillet I'm pretty sure it's not fluid, it's set in the main CSS file. Feel free to check it yourself though. :)